# Replicating variable-width TABLE column behavior with DIV/css

Tags: html, css

I have spent the better part of 4 hours struggling with what has got to be simple: replicating the behavior of the old HTML table columns with DIVs.

This layout is within a DIV at a higher level.

I have a simple three-column layout inside the DIV:

- Column-1 has text. I want it as narrow as possible without breaking text (i.e., as wide as the longest word).
- Column-2 is fixed-width.
- Column-3 takes up all remaining space, and includes a button placed in the upper right corner.

With tables, the layout is trivial:

```
<table><tr>
  <td width=1%>Foo&nbsp;Bar Baz</td>
  <td width=150px><img src="foo.jpg"></td>
  <td width=100%><div style="float:right">Button</div>Other stuff. </td>
</tr></table>
```

This works fine in all browsers except Firefox, which doesn't like the table inside the containing DIV.

With DIVs and css, I just can't get things to work.   Specifically:
 - I can NOT figure out what CSS to use to break the first column's width so Foo Bar is on the first line, and Baz soft-wraps.
 - I can NOT figure out how to expand the third column to take the remaining space after the first two columns.

I have tried numerous combinations of width:auto, float:left, word-wrap settings, and any other answer I could find here and elsewhere on the net.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works. I've added a few colors into my code.

```
<style>
#parent {overflow: hidden; background: #eee}
#a, #b {float: left;}

#a {background: #000; width: 1%;}
#b {background: #666; width: 150px;}
#c {background: #fc0; overflow: hidden}

button {float: right;}
</style>

<div id="parent">
    <div id="a">
        <p>Lorem <br>ipsum<br>dolor<br>sit<br>amet</p>
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        <p>Lorem <br>ipsum<br>dolor<br>sit<br>amet</p>
    </div>
    <div id="c">
        <button>button</button>
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9X7gy/2/

Comment: thanks for the attempt, but to me the leftmost div (a) is showing with 1% width, not expanding to fit the longest word (Lorem).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn´t know you want that. So, just remove `width` from `#a`. A updated fiddle in my post.

Comment: THANK YOU!   It looks like the magic combination is no width on #a  and overflow:hidden on #c.